Twilio: Maximum number of Queues per account
Can someone please tell me if there is a limit on maximum number of queues in twilio per account or subaccount.
i am developing a phone system where based on several conditions, a call is enqueued in a queue. The conditions can run into thousands. I am worried if there is a maximum limit on number of call queues in twilio
Finding the maximum limit on call queues in twilio
Edit1: I need the maximum limit on number of call queues per account or sub account. Not number of calls per queueu

Voice tasks or calls are limited to 100 by default per queue.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/twiml-queue-calls

i want to know maximum limit on number of call queues per account or sub account. Not number of calls per queueue

There is no queue limit definition in Twilio.
The limit is by number of tasks within the queue and within the workspace
